# Call OPC-UA method with UA-.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, opc, opc-ua

I am trying to call an OPC-UA method "ReadVar" from a SINUMERIK 840d, by using the Open OPC-UA.NET implementation at https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NET

I have limited knowledge about how to use this stack implementation and wonder if somebody has a lightweight example of how to use it to connect to the OPC-UA server and call the method from C# code?

I have tried with the Unified Automation trial binary client to test to call this method and it works perfectly. I also would wonder what is the key benefits (except for obvious ones with support etc) of buying a commercial OPC-UA SDK rather than using the above mentioned open source version.

Comment: The OPC Foundation implementation is mainly the stack + a sample SDK library on top. It was the original reference implementation, but is not actively developed any more, except for the stack layer. Unified Architecture SDK is the "Version 2" of the SDK interface and comes with an improved design, documentation and support.

Answer (score 3):

You have to know the node id of the method, the node id of the "object" of the method, and its arguments. Using the example provided in the OPC-UA .Net you can execute classic "hello world" :-)

```
IList<object> val = session.Call(  
  // I know that this node holds the method I like to use
  new NodeId("Methods", 2), 
  // and I know this node is "hello" method 
  new NodeId("Methods_Hello", 2), 
  "world");

Console.WriteLine(val[0]);
```

Comment: You are my hero! ;)